# html table formatting

Tags: html, html-table

Is there any way to specify the size of a table without changing the size of the cells?

In other words, my table has a border around it and I am using it for a menu:

```
<table width = "500" height = "300">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="mysite.com/contact.html">Contact</a>
</td>
<td rowspan = "2">
This is the area where news and updates will appear on the right hand side.
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="mysite.com/links.html">Links</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

First of all, is there a better way to do this?

If I change the height of the table like that the cells become too spaced out and the menu starts to look awkward.

Comment: Don't use tables for menus.  Use an unordered list instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry for the beginner question but is there a way to get rid of the dots next to the menu items? I am using it as so: <ul><li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li></ul>

Comment: Sure, `list-style-type: none;` will get rid of them

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can put the menu items in an unordered list. But what about getting the news and updates text on the right hand side of the page? Would it still be bad to have a table with just 2 cells (the unordered list on the left and the text on the right)? Any tips for this?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use tables for layout.  Menus in HTML4 should be in an unordered list.

Then you should use CSS to style it however you want.

Comment: an unordered list is btw a `<ul><li>listitem1</li></ul>`

Comment: Thanks Toby. I have the unordered list working for the menu items now but I am still wondering the best way to arrange the menu items and the page text (news and updates). Do you have any suggestions as to how to arrange my unordered list of menu items on the left and the main page text on the right?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a table layout? Use `div` elements and style them as you wish in CSS.

You can specify a certain width for the container and width in percentage for its children, so you've only one value to change.

And don't specify height in CSS, only min-height, or you'll block users from zooming at their will.

edit: and inside one of the `div`, an unordered list for navigation links :)

Comment: Surely wrapping a ul in a div is tag soup.

Comment: I tried many times not to wrap an ul in a div on projects for clients but there's so often one more bg image or border or whatever to add ... In the case of IE7 support, no multi-bg and no HTML5 nav element but plain (X)HTML, of course. One div isn't a "soup", it's just a supernumerary div, relax.

Comment: If it is needed for any reason at all then of course it should be used, I just thought it odd to immediately place it inside the div in this solution.